# Summary of Differences Between Mobile WebApp and Native Application

Tags: android, ios, web-applications

I am trying to get some of the larger differences/limitations/pros/cons etc between a web application and a native application for smartphones- either iOS or Android.

In my search I've obviously come across the idea that webapps are more or less cross platform functional from the start while native apps have to be in their own language (again obvious). I'm confused on the limitations on this aspect with the web application... Can I use specific phone functions/data if running a web app: reminder's and alarms, GPS data, etc. Can I code a web app in such a way that it doesn't run/load a new page as if I were navigating in a browser- the feel of a native app?

Overall, I'm looking for that specific information above, but also anything else contrasting the two in general. I'm trying to decide if I should learn both iOS and Android, or if most application functionality is available with a webapp.

Thanks!

Comment: Well I will offer my own biased opinion:  Web apps are slow, non-responsive, have limited capabilities and are usually ugly because everything has to be done in CSS in order to make every browser happy.  Native apps are the opposite of all of those (except for the ugly part which is still very possible).  There might come a day when mobile web apps are feasible for everything but I doubt I will still be alive.  http://sealedabstract.com/rants/why-mobile-web-apps-are-slow/

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://thinkmobile.appcelerator.com/blog/bid/284174/Native-vs-HTML5-looked-at-objectively-the-debate-is-over) comparison in 9 points.

> Overall, it’s a strong 5 to 3 win for native development, with one comparison a wash. The icing on the cake is the shear number of native apps now out there and the low current developer interest in building on HTML5.
>
> Looked at objectively, then, the world has already spoken on native versus HTML5, and it’s bizarre that some people seem to be confused about this still.